# Weird behavior of Derivative

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I have noticed a weird behavior of the "Derivative" operator, and I would like to know to why is this happening and if it is intended, as I'm using this function quite a bit in my code and I would like for it to work. Here is a code snippet that reproduces de problem :

```
f1[λ_, v_] := f2[λ, vectrans[v]]
f2[λ_, v_] :=λ (v[[1]] + v[[2]])
vectrans[v_] := ( {
    {0, 2},
    {2, 0}
   } ) . v
f1[λ, {a, b}]
Derivative[1, 0][f1][λ, {a, b}]
D[f1[λ, {a, b}], λ]
```

Now if you look at the output of this code, I coded the function `f1` to get a scalar and a vector as input, and spit out $λ(2a+2b)$, if the inputs are $λ$ and $v=\{a,b\}$. Then, in the first attempt I use the operator `Derivative[1,0]` to do the partial derivative w.r.t. $\lambda$, but I get the following output with mathematica 13 :

```
{{{a, b}, {2 + a, 2 + b}}, {{2 + a, 2 + b}, {a, b}}}
```

Which honestly I have no idea how it comes about.

If we use instead the operator `D`, we get the expect result $2a+2b$.

Why is that ?

Comment: `Derivative`, in effect, differentiates `f1[\[Lambda], x]` and then replaces `x` by `{a, b}`. `D` differentiates the result of `f1[\[Lambda], {a, b}]`.

Comment: I see. I will try to include conditions on the parameters of f1 to see if it changes anything.

Comment: Indeed, adding a ListQ to the v parameter just prevents Derivative from computing the derivative altogether, as f1 just doesn't evaluate... Apparently using "Derivative[1,{0,0}]" works, as it then knows that the second parameter is a vector.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So the problem as pointed in the comments was that `Derivative` will assume all parameters of the function to be differentiated are scalars, in other words it differentiates `f[λ,x]` and then replaces x by `{a,b}`, which gives the unexpected result.

One way around this, while still using `Derivative` is as follows :

```
Derivative[1,{0,0}][f1][λ,{a,b}]
```

This was indeed written in the Documentation, but I had missed it :

`Derivative[{n1,n2,…}][f]` represents the derivative of `f[{x1,x2,…}]` taken $n_i$ times with respect to $x_i$. In general, arguments given in lists in `f` can be handled by using a corresponding list structure in Derivative.